# PySide2, Threading and Images

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyside

I have a simple code that gradually loads a large number of images while the UI remains responsive. This works OK on PySide6, PyQt5 and PyQt6, **but** on PySide2 the interface lags and the images appear only after they are fully loaded.

```
import glob
from PySide2 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui
from PySide2.QtCore import QThread, QObject,  Signal,  Slot
import sys

dir_path = 'F:/img/'  # image directory #  

class Worker(QObject):
    progress = Signal(QtGui.QImage)
    
    @Slot()
    def do_work(self):
           
        res = glob.glob(dir_path+'*.png')+glob.glob(dir_path+'*.jpg')
        for path in res:
            icon = QtGui.QImage(path)
            self.progress.emit(icon)

class Demo(QtWidgets.QWidget):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)  
        self.setGeometry(500, 300, 900, 530)
        self.setWindowTitle('Demo')
        
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self)
        self.listWidget = QtWidgets.QListWidget()
        self.listWidget.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(100, 100))
        self.listWidget.setGridSize(QtCore.QSize(120, 130))               
        self.listWidget.setDefaultDropAction(QtCore.Qt.MoveAction)                    
        self.listWidget.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.NoFrame)
        self.listWidget.setResizeMode(QtWidgets.QListView.Adjust)
        self.listWidget.setViewMode(QtWidgets.QListView.IconMode)
        self.listWidget.setMovement(QtWidgets.QListView.Static)
        self.listWidget.setUpdatesEnabled(True)

        self.worker = Worker()
        self.thread = QThread()

        self.worker.progress.connect(self.update_progress)
        self.worker.moveToThread(self.thread)
        self.thread.started.connect(self.worker.do_work)

        self.thread.start()
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.listWidget)  
                
    def update_progress(self, img):
      pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap()
      pixmap.convertFromImage(img)
      icon = QtGui.QIcon()
      icon.addPixmap(pixmap, QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
      item = QtWidgets.QListWidgetItem()
      item.setIcon(icon)
      self.listWidget.addItem(item)

app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
ex = Demo()
ex.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

My question is: How do I get the same behavior on PySide2 as on PySide6?

Comment: Try to remove the `@Slot()` decorator.

Comment: @musicamante Thanks for the answer, but it didn't help

Comment: Then try to move the `progress` connection *after* `moveToThread()` (and eventually try to restore the slot). Also try to add a small delay at each iteration of the for loop, like `self.msleep(10)`. Are you using a IDE and/or debugger? Try to run the code outside of it, as in certain conditions it might affect the result. Are you using the the python bindings for the same Qt libraries in PyQt5 and PySide2, or are you using their own? If not, what versions are they?

Comment: I added  `time.sleep(0.01)` to the loop and it works for some reason.  Thank you very much for help @musicamante

Comment: Good to know. Unfortunately, I cannot provide a valid and acceptable explanation of the reason (it would really help to know more about your OS and configuration, see the last question of my comment above), but it may a combination of aspects. 1. while I/O is normally what properly allows threading (since file access means *waiting* for the data, which allows the GIL to transfer control to other threads) there are situations for which that is still not enough, because access and processing of that data may not be allow to release the GIL; 2. while identical in concept, PySide and PyQt, are »

Comment: » not the same thing (and that's why they cannot be used together), as they have some different ways of wrapping Qt objects, and some underlying and concept aspects (like threading) have slight differences in behavior. 99% of the time, they do behave in the same way, but there are some small exceptions that depend on the way the binder (Shiboken for PySide, SIP for PyQt) accesses Qt objects and how Python/C++ objects "communicate", and the GIL may, again, come in play for various reasons: Qt can use concurring threads, but Python cannot. If you have for/while loops in your thread, and unless »

Comment: » you are absolutely sure that some "wait" condition happens there (queue access, socket/network waiting, etc), it's usually better and safer to always add a small sleep at defined points and/or each iteration. It may result in a slightly slower result in the long run, but that, other than necessary, is also acceptable considering that we are adding complexity levels to a program, such as threading.